# Count combination of factors

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Ok, so this problem seems easy but I can't figure it out. Basically I have the following data.table structure:

```
dt =data.table(group=sample(c("A","B"),10,replace=T),
fact=sample(c("Q","R","S","v"),10,replace=T))

group   fact
1   B   Q
2   B   S
3   A   S
4   B   S
5   A   Q
6   B   v
7   A   v
8   A   S
9   B   Q
10  A   R
```

Now I would like to find the amount of each combination of group and fact.

```
group   fact    V1
1   B   Q     2
2   B   S     2
3   A   S     2
4   B   S     1
5   A   Q     1
6   B   v     1
etc.
```

I can't seem to figure it out using data.table.
The following only gives me the unique factors.

```
dt=dt[,length(unique(fact)),by=list(group,fact)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a data.frame with

```
as.data.frame(table(dt$group, dt$fact))
```

You can then cast this back to data.table, and subset on Freq!=0, etc.

Or a data.table version with

```
dt[,list(freq=.N), by=list(group, fact)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.N` like this:

```
dt[, .N, by=list(group, fact)]
```

Read `help("data.table")` to learn about `.N` and its helpful friends.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution using `n()`:

```
dt %>% group_by(group, fact) %>% summarise(N = n())
```